# Codeigniter insert where MySql table has auto increment id?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

Problem: When I add an **id** field, primary key, auto_increment, my insert statement no longer inserts a record into my table.

Before I added the **id** field, I was using a varchar field with unique strings as the primary key. But, now I want to add a straight id - integer, primary_key, auto_increment.
Seems like there should be dozens of questions about this on the web.

Instead, I find all questions have to do with `$this->db->insert_id()`. But `$this->db->insert_id()` is more like a read, and does nothing to make my insert statement successful.

Right now, I construct an array call $fielddata, and populate each array element with data from a form, like so (highly simplified):

```
$fielddata['member_id'] = 'abcdefghi12345';
$fielddata['name'] = 'John Smith';
$fielddata['email'] = 'jsmith@gmail.com';

$this->db->insert('members', $fielddata);
```

I have tried things like:

```
$fielddata['id'] = '';
```

...or,

```
$fielddata['id'] = 0;
```

...but nothing works.

**UPDATE:**
My problem was that I was trying to set an array element to a post element that I was not actually passing from the form. For some reason CodeIgniter didn't throw an error, so I kept thinking the problem must be at the query line. It wasn't. Once I added the form field to my form, and matched all array elements to all form elements (of course leaving out "Submit" and other hidden fields that were not table fields), the `insert` worked.

Comment: Are you sure that **id** is now your table's primary key? What does your table look like right now?

Comment: @xiankai , Yes, id is my table's primary key. As usual, my problem was an error before the insert line, and nothing to do with the table/database. I was going to delete this question, but I think others will find it and use it to discover their own coding errors, where they think it's a sql error, but really a data preparation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your table structure?

**test Table:** 
id (AUTO INC 10) 
member_id (VARCHAR 10) 
name (VARCHAR 10) 
email (VARCHAR 15)

```
$fielddata['member_id'] = 'abcdefghi12345';
$fielddata['name'] = 'John Smith';
$fielddata['email'] = 'jsmith@gmail.com';

$this->db->insert('test', $fielddata);
```

Create table name 'test' and test if this is working..

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to set an array element to a post element that I was not actually passing from the form. For some reason CodeIgniter didn't throw an error, so I kept thinking the problem must be at the query line. It wasn't. Once I added the form field to my form, and matched all array elements to all form elements (of course leaving out "Submit" and other hidden fields that were not table fields), the `insert` worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No need to specify your id if it's auto incrementing. Just ignore the field and let MySQL deal with it.